# What is the complexity of using list() while copying a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, time-complexity, big-o

I have a list:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

and now I want to make a copy of the list `a` as list `b`

```
b = list(a)
```

I want to know the complexity of the step where I make a copy of the list `a`.

Comment: It's O(1), of course.  There has to be a variable size (or some such parameter) for anything like O(n) to even make sense.

Comment: @jasonharper I can't tell if you are joking or just nitpicking, but it is clearly O(n) where n is the length of the list. Passing a list argument to the list constructor is basically the same thing as calling `.copy()`: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list

Comment: Nitpicking (explained), it is O(1), as `len(a) == 4` (guaranteed by specific question statements). Most would not refute a tuple-4-copy or destructure-assign-4 has a constant copy time. However, that’s not a generalized / useful answer to copying an *arbitrary* list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a copy operation on mutable datatypes:

```
b = list(a)
a is b # False
```

It copies the whole data to another memory location and the time complexity is defined by the total size of the list i.e. **O(n)**

If you had assigned it like following (*Aliasing*):

```
b = a
a is b # True
```

Then the time complexity would be **O(1)**

For more detail look [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: `a = b` isn't a copy though, it's aliasing (also, you got it backwards; `a` is the original, so making an alias named `b` would be `b = a`).

Comment: hehe. thankyou :) @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 3):

When a list is copied:

- `list.copy()`
- `list[:]`
- `list()`

It iterates thorugh all elements. So the time complexity defined by thr size of the list i.e. `O(n)`

Answer (score 2):

Shallow Copying, Slicing takes O(n)
Because Python goes over all elements in the list and adds a copy of the object reference to the new list (copy by reference).

**Shallow Copying**

`list.copy()`

**List Slicing**

`list[:]`

**use the built-in list constructor list(...)**

`list()`

**Use list comprehension**

`[e for e in lst]`